# Changing modal popup trigger from button click to on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, modal-dialog, onload

I have a modal on my page. Currently, it is set to pop up when you press a button. However, I want it to pop up when the page loads. Ideally, it would only popup the first time a user visits the site.

The snippet:

```js
// Popup Window
var scrollTop = '';
var newHeight = '100';

$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    newHeight = scrollTop + 100;
});

$('.popup-trigger').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (jQuery(window).width() < 767) {
        $(this).after($(".popup"));
        $('.popup').show().addClass('popup-mobile').css('top', 0);
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('.popup').offset().top
        }, 500);
    } else {
        $('.popup').removeClass('popup-mobile').css('top', newHeight).toggle();
    }
    ;
});

$('html').click(function () {
    $('.popup').hide();
});

$('.popup-btn-close').click(function (e) {
    $('.popup').hide();
});

$('.popup').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.popup-trigger {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    max-width: 260px;
    background: #4EBD79;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.popup {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 700px;
    margin-left: -350px;
    padding: 50px 30px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 19px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border: 10px solid #150E2D;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.popup-mobile {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 30px 0 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.popup-btn-close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 14px;
    color: #4EBD79;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a class="popup-trigger">Open Pop Up</a>

<div class="main">
    Page text
</div>

<div class="popup">
    Modal Text
    <span class="popup-btn-close">close</span>
</div>
```

I don't want to use `popup-trigger` button anymore, I just want to have the modal show up when the page loads.

I have tried replacing 
`$('.popup-trigger').click(function(e) {`

with:
`$(document).load(function() {`

no luck there.

Any ideas? Also, i just got into cookies, but not sure how they work. How would I have it such that it only appears the first time someone visits the site per certain time frame, e.g. per day.

Comment: check with $(document).ready

Answer (score 0):

You can perfom this by storing a cookies information (to check first visite of a user) and also use jquery ready to open the poupu on startup after checking the cookies .

Here you can find a **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bRIMOs/44namwfq/)** ( stack snippet doesn't give permission to use cookies , run the fiddle twice then the pupup will disapear )

PS : I ve created show popup function to prevent duplicate code, also i've removed the line //$`(this).after($(".popup"));` which remove the div popup ??!

Also I used Jquery cookie lib to access and et cookies

See code here

**JS :**

```
var scrollTop = '';
var newHeight = '100';

$(function() {
    console.log($.cookie("openPop"));
    if($.cookie('openPop')){
      $.cookie('openPop',false);
      showPopup();
    }
    else 
      $.cookie('name',true);
});

$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
  scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  newHeight = scrollTop + 100;
});

$('.popup-trigger').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  showPopup();
});


function showPopup() {
  scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  newHeight = scrollTop + 100;

  if (jQuery(window).width() < 767) {
    //$(this).after($(".popup"));
    $('.popup').show().addClass('popup-mobile').css('top', 0);
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('.popup').offset().top
    }, 500);
  } else {
    $('.popup').removeClass('popup-mobile').css('top', newHeight).toggle();
  };
}

$('html').click(function() {
  $('.popup').hide();
});

$('.popup-btn-close').click(function(e) {
  $('.popup').hide();
});

$('.popup').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**CSS :**

```
.popup-trigger {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 260px;
  background: #4EBD79;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popup {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 700px;
  margin-left: -350px;
  padding: 50px 30px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 10px solid #150E2D;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.popup-mobile {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 30px 0 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.popup-btn-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 14px;
  color: #4EBD79;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**HTML :**

```
  <src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a class="popup-trigger">Open Pop Up</a>

<div class="main">
  Page text
</div>

<div class="popup">
  Modal Text
  <span class="popup-btn-close">close</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding click listeners, why don't you try calling the `$('.popup').show()` directly after onload.
Check this fiddle, hope it works for you.
https://jsfiddle.net/kajalc/h4fomm5q/

If this is fine then the button and its event can be removed from the script.

Answer (score 0):

Removed use of button to trigger the modal.
Check this, if it works for you.

```js
// Popup Window
  var scrollTop = '';
  var newHeight = '100';
  if (jQuery(window).width() < 767) {
    $('.popup').show().addClass('popup-mobile').css('top', 0);
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('.popup').offset().top
    }, 500);
  } else {
    $('.popup').removeClass('popup-mobile').css('top', newHeight).toggle();
  }

  $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    newHeight = scrollTop + 100;
  });

  $('.popup-btn-close').click(function(e) {
    $('.popup').hide();
  });
```

```css
   

.popup {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 700px;
    margin-left: -350px;
    padding: 50px 30px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 19px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border: 10px solid #150E2D;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.popup-mobile {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 30px 0 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.popup-btn-close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 14px;
    color: #4EBD79;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
    Page text
</div>

<div class="popup">
    Modal Text
    <span class="popup-btn-close">close</span>
</div>
```